# Running module with parameters inside notebook - Python

Tags: python

I'm have a module which i can run from the python interpreter like this :

```
python -m bin.train ..... long set of parameters ...
```

And the thing is that is results a little uncomfortable giving the length of the parameters, And also i would like to run the code inside a python notebook.

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Long days and pleasant nights :) Err, what do you mean by run it inside a notebook - what's stopping you doing so at the moment?

Comment: Hi!  i'm trying to figure out how to pass all my parameters to the module. From the interpreter i just add the parameters as usual : --config_paths="lblabla" but inside the notebook I'm not quite sure how to do that.